# Approaches to implement tapped inserting table cell with radio buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

What I'm trying to do is to insert some new data into the data source array, and then do [tableView reloadData]. The new array can be inserted, but there are two problems.

1) I want to have two radio buttons in the new cell for users to choose. Should I define a new cell object or something?

2) When reloading the data, the selected cell's color cannot be set to green as before.

Or any other suggestions on how to best implement this, thanks!!:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, what I would do is pre-layout that cell containing the two radio buttons either in the storyboard (You can also do it in a .xib file). Then I will set an identifier for it like "LanguageSkillSelectionTableViewCell" or something. After that, when I am about to load the new set of data into the table view I can manage the presentation of cells in the table view through the callback `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

An example would be if I want to load that LanguageSkillSelectionTableViewCell always at the beginning, then I would just set it at indexPath.row == 0. else set the contents of the data list to other rows.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableCell;

    if(_loadedNewData)
    {
        if(indexPath.row < dataList.count && indexPath.row > 0)
        {
            tableCell = (DataTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DataTableViewCell"];

            //set attributes of the tableCell
        }

        else
        {
            tableCell = (LanguageSkillSelectionTablViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LanguageSkillSelectionTableViewCell"];

            //set attributes of the tableCell
        }
    }

    else
    {
        //load in default order
    }

    return tableCell;
}
```

You can just play with the arrangement and presentation of the cells under this callback.

For the second problem, you have to store a flag or state for that selection picked by the user in a global variable within the class. Then everytime the cells are reloaded you can just update the selection state of that cell by setting a method for that cell that would update the selection state of the radio button.

For example:

If user selected English, then it would be like:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableCell;

    if(_loadedNewData)
    {
        if(indexPath.row < dataList.count && indexPath.row > 0)
        {
            tableCell = (DataTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DataTableViewCell"];

            //set attributes of the tableCell
        }

        else
        {
            tableCell = (LanguageSkillSelectionTablViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LanguageSkillSelectionTableViewCell"];

            //set attributes of the tableCell

            [(LanguageSkillSelectionTablViewCell *)tableCell setLanguageSelectionState:canReadWrite];
        }
    }

    else
    {
        //load in default order
    }

    return tableCell;
}
```